# Chrome extension: Call function in contentscript.js from background.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a DIV contains message if the user visits the URL stored in my database. Actually, it works in an alert message but I want DIV, so I should to access the DOM of the page by contentscript.js and it's work but how can I prevent the function work in contentscript.js because I want the function work after I checked the URL in background.js!

I read about tab but it's run only when the user clicks a browser action's icon and in my situation the user didn't click any icon he just browsing in www.

contentscript.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(window.location.href);
var pathname = window.location.pathname; // Returns path only
var url      = window.location.href; 
//document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerText

function MessageBox(){
    document.documentElement.style.height = '100%';
    document.body.style.height = '100%';
    document.documentElement.style.width = '100%';
    document.body.style.width = '100%';

    var div = document.createElement( 'div' );
    var btnForm = document.createElement( 'form' );
    var btn = document.createElement( 'input' );

    //append all elements
    document.body.appendChild( div );
    div.appendChild( btnForm );
    btnForm.appendChild( btn );
    //set attributes for div
    div.id = 'myDivId';
    div.style.position = 'fixed';
    div.style.top = '80%';
    div.style.left = '77%';
    div.style.width = '22%';   
    div.style.height = '17%';
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    div.style.border='1px solid red';

    //set attributes for btnForm
    btnForm.action = '';

    //set attributes for btn
    //"btn.removeAttribute( 'style' );
    btn.type = 'button';
    btn.value = 'X';
    btn.style.position = 'reltive';
    btn.style.top = '10%';
    btn.style.left = '80%';
    btn.style.width = '5%';   
    btn.style.height = '3%';   
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response, sender, sendResponse) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://mywebsite.com/api/route',
        dataType: 'json',
    }).success(function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            if (results[i].url === response) {
                alert("This page in my database"); // this work but I don't want an alert message
            } //if
        } //for
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chrome.runtime.sendMessage` is asynchronous method. You can pass it callback method and in background script call `sendResponse` when you finishes your work

In your background script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response, sender, sendResponse) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://mywebsite.com/api/route',
        dataType: 'json',
    }).success(function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            if (results[i].url === response) {
                sendResponse(true);
                return;
            }
        }

        sendResponse(false);
    });

    return true; // tell chrome about runnning async job
});
```

And in your content script do this

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(window.location.href, function(result) {
    if (result) {
        // Found
        MessageBox();
    }
});
```

Read more about message passing here https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging